# How to create a Package with Python-for-Android in windows?

Tags: android, python, git, kivy

I am using `Kivy framework`. I want to create a package for android using the `python-for-android` project in windows 7. I read this link http://kivy.org/docs/guide/packaging-android.html. The **Buildozer** as I read automates the entire build process but it currently works only in Linux. The other method given here uses `git` which I am not aware of much and it also says that you'll need a linux computer or a virtual machine. Please furnish me with some method to create a complete `apk package` without the git knowledge `in the windows`. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you dont build it in windows ... you build it in linux ... luckily they made it easy to run linux in windows.

1. you download oracle virtualbox and a linux image

https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads

<s>2. then you download the image that kivy provides that is all setup to build android packages for you</s>

http://kivy.org/docs/guide/packaging-android-vm.html

(you now have a linux machine ready to build on)

3. then you build in the virtualbox following the standard build procedure outlined here
   http://kivy.org/docs/guide/packaging-android.html#packaging-your-application-into-apk

Comment: After installing buildozer in the system, it says- navigate to your project directory and run: `buildozer init`. I have my project directory at the desktop of windows. How can I navigate the Ubuntu terminal to my windows desktop(I am running Ubuntu on the VirtualBox)? Or is there any alternate method to do so? - Joran Beasley

Comment: you use ftp to put it in your virtual box ... or you use virtual box shared folders thing .... (I just move the files to the vm)

Comment: Seems like the VM is not there anymore

Comment: they removed the VM from the site. you may try ubuntu or lubuntu (lite version of ubuntu) in VM and use pendrive or phone with USB to transfer data between WIndows and Linux (because, shared folder seems quite unresoponsive in Lubuntu and requires some ugly terminal works to connect the shared folder.)

so i recommandd to use USB stuffs (pendrive or phone)